# Removing dynamically generated buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm working with C# windows forms and need some help. I have a button that creates other buttons and adds them to the list 'buttons'. I need to have each button created destroy itself when it is clicked.

```
        //create new button
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Name = "aButt"+buttNum;
        Debug.WriteLine(newButton.Name);
        buttNum++;

        newButton.Text = "Button!";
        newButton.Height = 50;
        newButton.Width = 50;

        //controls where the new button gets placed
        if (curX > 9)
        {
            curX = 0;
            curY++;
            //defines the point the button spawns
            newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((curX * 55)+10, curY * 55);
            //increments X to avoid placing a button on top of another
            curX++;

        }
        else
        {
            newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((curX * 55) + 10, curY * 55);
            curX++;
        }


        newButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.removeThisButton);
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);
```

I have the event listener set up, but since the sender has no actual information on the button itself i'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms app? WPF? I'd like to add more specific tags to help attract experts.

Answer (score 2):

The click event handler has the signature

`private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

The `object sender` is the source of the event. Just cast that to a `Button`, and there's what got clicked:

```
    Button whatWasClicked = sender as Button;
    if(whatWasClicked == null)
        // never mind -- it wasn't a button...
```

Comment: You can, however call this method from anywhere, not necessarily a button. It would be good to check and make sure the sender is the button.

Comment: True enough. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Sender *is* the button. You can remove it from Form's control collection like this:

```
private void removeThisButton(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Controls.Remove(sender);
}
```